Why did Abraham go back to Haran?
Why did Abraham ignore God's command while in Mesopotamia and choose to make a turnaround to Haran instead of going to the land God would show him?

Questions on the Stack Exchange platform are expected to be researched and to be supported by citation and reference. The above question expresses an opinion 'ignore God's command' without any support from the text. The question needs to consider the presence and the influence of Abraham's father. Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and the Help, below, as to the functioning and the purpose of the site.

Doesn't the settement in Haran (ch11 v31) come before the command (ch12 v1)?

@StephenDisraeli while the command is recorded later, 12:1 says "had said" which makes it somewhat unclear at what point God gave the command.

The premise of the OP is not correct, Abraham did not "make a turnaround to Haran", Haran is on the way from Ur to the Promised Land. Ur was in southern Mesopotamia, Haran was in north Mesopotamia.  The family had much livestock so the only possible route they could have taken into the Levant was to go north next to the Euphrates river via the "fertile crescent" and then south from Haran.
En route, he stopped at Haran. There is no clear indication it was disobedience, or lack of faith.
Stephen, the first Christian martyr, on the day he was killed, said:

"Men, brothers, and fathers, listen. The God of glory appeared to our father Abraham, when he was in Mesopotamia, before he dwelt in Haran, and said to him, Get thee out of thy country, and from thy kindred, and come into the land which I will show thee. Then came he out of the land of the Chaldaeans, and dwelt in Haran: and from thence, when his father was dead, he removed him into this land, wherein ye now dwell", Acts 7:2-4.  See also Joshua 24:1-3.

From Genesis 11:31, it seems that the journey from Ur to Haran was instigated, not by Abraham, but by Terah, Abraham's father: "And Terah took Abram.. to go forth into the land of Canaan, and came to Haran and dwelt there".  Terah was leading the journey. Stephen tells us Abraham did not continue on into Canaan until Terah had died. Terah did not take Nahor out of Ur.  We are not told if Nahor had left Ur and settled in Haran before or after Terah's journey. But that Nahor also settled in Haran we can be sure because Laban his descendant lived there, Gen 27:43. See also Gen 24:4.
Genesis 12:1, "Now the LORD had said...": He had said it to Abraham while he was in Ur, probably many years earlier. One possibility is that Nahor followed them out of Ur to Haran at a later date, making it clear to Abraham that he needed to move yet again away from his father's kindred.  Another possibility is that Terah was too ill to continue the journey.
Whether Abraham was disobedient in not immediately going all the way into Canaan we simply cannot be sure.  If it was disobedience, we have another example of the patience and amazing grace of God.
When Jonah disobeyed God and failed to go preach at Ninevah we read "the word of the LORD came to Jonah the second time", Jonah 3:1.  We do not read anything similar spoken to Abraham. On the contrary, his journey is always held up as an example of faith, Hebrews 11:8. On the other hand, repentance, trusting in God's gracious mercy, and resuming our obedience to God after a time of disobedience also requires great faith.
